# INSERT INTO with multiple parameters via VB6 & ADO

Tags: sql-server, parameters, vb6, sql-insert, ado

I'm trying to update some legacy VB6 code by adding a simple error logging subroutine using ADO to insert a row into a SQL Server table with basic details of the error.  The subroutine receives an integer parameter value (`errorCode`) that identifies the error type.  The error will have occurred while parsing an XML file.  The XML file name (obtained via `objFile.Name`) is to be logged along with the date, the user name and the `errorCode` parameter value.

The code below shows where I am so far.  The table I'm trying to INSERT INTO looks like this:

```
[dbo].[tblXMLerrorLog](
[errorLogID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[runDate] [datetime2](0) NULL,
[runBy] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[xmlFileWithError] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
[errorCode] [int] NULL)
```

```
Sub writeErrorLog(errorCode As Integer)

  strSQL = "INSERT INTO dbo.tblXMLerrorLog (runDate, runBy, xmlFileWithError, errorCode) 
            VALUES(GetDate(), Current_User,?,?);"

  With cmd

    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = strSQL

    Set par1 = .CreateParameter("@xmlFileWithError", adChar, adParamInput, 50, objFile.Name)
    .Parameters.Append par1

    Set par2 = .CreateParameter("@errorCode", adInteger, adParamInput, , errorCode)
    .Parameters.Append par2

    .ActiveConnection = Cnxn
    .Execute                        ' update error log

    .Parameters.Delete ("@xmlFileWithError")
    .Parameters.Delete ("@errorCode")

  End With

End Sub
```

When I run the code the `.Execute` statement throws this error:

> "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors.  Check each OLE DB
>   status value, if available.  No work was done."

My research of that error message suggests a field size mismatch but I don't understand that.  I'd appreciate any direction.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is many years since I used VB6, so forgive me if I am wrong, but I think you should try adVarChar as the data type of your first parameter.

Comment: Jonathan: thanks for your suggestion.  I tried that but I still get the same error.

Comment: Try adVarWChar instead. Your SQL table has nvarchar. Also, why are you restricting the length to 50 when the table field has,255? This latter won't be the problem, I am just curious.

Comment: Two other things I have thought of, which might cause a problem.  Firstly what is the actual file name being passed?  Please check that it has no strange characters.  Secondly, you could try altering your table definition to make runDate default to `GETDATE()` and runBy default to `CURRENT_USER`.  That way your sql need only have two values inserted.  This might simplify the issue.

Comment: Having got to work I have had a chance to run your code on an old machine.  I cannot repeat your error, which leads me to suspect strongly that the problem lies with objFile.Name.  Please post what this value is.

Comment: You can also run a Profiler Trace and look at the generated sp_executesql call that's dispatched to the DB for clues.

Comment: Jonathan: Many thanks for your help with this.  objFile.Name is 1333457-00.xml in the error situation that triggers the subroutine.

Comment: Therein lies your problem, I think. The value parameter takes an object, and oledb tries to interpret the data type. I strongly suspect that it is trying to interpret so many digits followed by a minus sign as numeric. Try prefacing the file name with some letters before you pass the filename (or even just use a random string instead). Let's be certain first that this is the problem.

Comment: Jonathan: I think I have figured out the problem (but not the solution).  My main program uses a parameter.  When my sub's .Execute statement is reached, there are 3 parameters.  The preferred solution would be to use named parameters, as suggested in another comment, but I don't think VB6 supports that--I have to reference them with '?'.  I suppose I could brute force it by saving the first parameter in the sub, then delete it, then add my 2 parameters, then delete them after executing the SQL, then restore the saved parameter.  But that's an unappealing kludge.  Is there a better way?

Comment: I should have added that I think the reason my subroutine code doesn't work is that the unexpected first parameter (from my main program) causes a data type mismatch when the INSERT INTO statement tries to stuff the 'wrong' value into a column having a different data type.  If I've got that right then the error message I'm seeing makes sense.

Comment: OK, I've fixed it.  My last 2 comments explain what I had done wrong.  The fix turned out to have nothing to do with the subroutine.  Instead I reworked my the main program so as to delete the first parameter before calling the subroutine.  Thanks to all who helped me with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed.  As explained in the comments, my main (calling) program uses a parameter.  So, when my subroutine's .Execute statement was reached, there were 3 parameters instead of just 2 as I'd naively expected.  The preferred solution would have been to use named parameters, as one comment suggested, but I don't think VB6 supports that; I have to reference the parameters with question mark placeholders, so their order matters.  My subroutine didn't work because the unexpected first parameter (from the calling program) caused a data type mismatch when the INSERT INTO statement tried to insert the 'wrong' value into a column having a different data type.  So the error message I was seeing made sense.  The fix had nothing to do with the subroutine.  Instead, I reworked the calling program so as to delete the first parameter before calling the subroutine. Thanks to all who helped me with this.